# iptables - DNAT after PREROUTING

Tags: routes, firewall, iptables

I have trouble setting up the correct iptables rule to change the destination of a forwarded package *after* prerouting. I have a rule to redirect all incoming port 80 traffic to my local port 3128 :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 3128
```

On port 3128, I'm running a transparent proxy that does some analysis on the traffic, then sends it to its actual location.

However, I want to treat traffic to `10.0.0.25:80` to be treated differently. I want it to go through the proxy on port 3128, *but then* have the destination changed to port 80 on *my* machine (`10.0.0.1:80`). I have tried the following, but it doesn't work, as the client device gets a message that says no service could be found at `10.0.0.25` :

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.25 -j REDIRECT --to 80
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what's wrong: Since `10.0.0.25` is one the same network as my client devices, it's only natural that no device would ever try to reach it via the gateway (`10.0.0.1`). They rather tried to reach it directly. Since `10.0.0.25` is just an address I made up (which was helping me with another routing issue), I changed it to an address on a different network and all was fine.